# Any idea how to use CodeCampServer template?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-templates, codecampserver

http://teamcity.codebetter.com/viewLog.html?buildId=11047&tab=artifacts&buildTypeId=bt21

CodeCampServer has two download packages: VisualStudioTemplate and CodeCampServerPackage.

I looked for any idea how to use them, but unfortunately I didn't. So, I ask my questions here:

1. How to use VisualStudioTemplate? the archive file did not contain any `.vstemplate` file, so it cannot be used as VisualStudio template. Do I need to rename any `$safesolutionname$` manually? It's not make any sense.
2. What the porpuse of CodeCampServerPackage? This archive file contains a deployment files only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Eric Hexter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/94665/eric-hexter) I have some answers:

The current trunk of CodeCampServer is on [CodePlex](http://codecampserver.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets). The build
server is moving right now from the *regular* [teamcity.codebetter](http://teamcity.codebetter.com)
server [here](http://teamcity.codebetter.com/viewLog.html?buildId=3D11047&tab=3Dar=tifacts&buildTypeId=3Dbt21) to a new build server of HeadSpring projects:
http://build1.headspringlabs.com/

1. VisualStudioTemplate is meant to be used with the [solution
   factory](http://solutionfactory.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets) command line tool. This tool basically takes the name of
   the new project, the directory of the source template, and the
   destination directory of the new project.
2. CodeCampServerPackage is a ready to use deployment files for site
   the power CodeCampServer, like: [codecampserver.com](http://codecampserver.com/),
   [adnug.org](http://adnug.org/) and [c4mvc.net](http://www.c4mvc.net/).

Again, big credit to [Eric Hexter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/94665/eric-hexter) for this answer.